# How to implement an onTap method for ListTile that removes itself from ListView when tapped?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement onTap method for my ListTile that so that I can remove it by tapping. I can't think of any way besides extracting the ListTile widget and passing in the list as a parameter but that obviously is gonna lead to circular reference.

Sample code

```
List<ListTile> list = [
 ListTile( onTap: () { /*Remove itself from the list*/ }, title: /*sometext*/ ),
 ListTile( onTap: () { /*Remove itself from the list*/ }, title: /*sometext*/ ),
 ListTile( onTap: () { /*Remove itself from the list*/ }, title: /*sometext*/ ),
];

class SetupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetupScreenState createState() => _SetupScreenState();
}

class _SetupScreenState extends State<SetupScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7, vertical: 12),
          child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: list.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return list[index];
           },
          ),
         ),
        ),
       };
}
}
```

I appreciate any suggestion on how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to restructure your code a bit.

Sample code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => ListViewDivider(),
      itemCount: transactions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return MyTransactionListItem(transaction: transactions[index], onTap:()=> _onTap(transactions[index],context),);
      },
    );
   // ListViewDivider() is just a class holding Divider()

  }
```

MyTransactionListItem just holds a ListTile. The point of interest is below. When the list tile item is tapped, the following function gets called. Now, you write whatever you want to do with it. E.g. deleting the item in your case. So, just remove the item from the list and wrap in the setState()

```
void _onTap(MyTransaction transaction, BuildContext context) {
    print('Tapped on : ${transaction.id}');
    setState( () => transactions.remove(facerecTransaction) );
  }
```

Note : Above is a sample code and not unit tested.